# Create File object type in TypeScript

Tags: file, typescript

I have a function that should only accept JS [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects.

How do I create that type in TypeScript?

edit: sharing my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./ts-dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es2017"
    ]
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*", "./test/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules", "dist"
]
}
```

Answer (score 30):

TypeScript has a defined interface for `File` which represents the file object in JavaScript. Generally you should look for types named as their Javascript countertypes. You can use this type in a parameter annotation for the parameter:

```
function processFile(file: File) {
    
}
```

Source: [microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/79e5e79ef7724066889fbce97e9e6d6db4e746b5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4706-L4712)

Comment: That's also what I expected, bit I get a "File is not defined" error. This is weird since ESLint accepts 'File' as a type.

Comment: @RemiV2 works in the playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20processFile(file%3A%20File)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D Do you have any `libs` defined in your `tsconfig.json` ? Maybe you omitted `dom` where `File` is probably defined

Comment: I have the "dom" option, the problem stays the same

Comment: @RemiV2 please add the tsconfig to the question, maybe I can spot something else wrong with it ..it's probably a config issue since it works in the playground

Comment: @RemiV2 are you sure that is the config that is getting picked-up ? I tried and it works, the only way I can get your error is if the lib does not include `dom`. Also run the build, maybe just your IDE is reporting ghost errors ..

Comment: There's also a `FileList` type for what a file input returns.